# Colorize Clusters in Dendogram with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dendextend, ggdendro

Didzis Elferts showed how to plot a dendogram using ggplot2 and ggdendro:

[horizontal dendrogram in R with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118033/horizontal-dendrogram-in-r-with-labels)

here is the code:

```
labs = paste("sta_",1:50,sep="") #new labels
rownames(USArrests)<-labs #set new row names
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")

library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)

#convert cluster object to use with ggplot
dendr <- dendro_data(hc, type="rectangle") 

#your own labels are supplied in geom_text() and label=label
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(data=segment(dendr), aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) + 
  geom_text(data=label(dendr), aes(x=x, y=y, label=label, hjust=0), size=3) +
  coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0.2, 0)) + 
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
        panel.grid=element_blank())
```

Does anyone know, how to colorize the different clusters? For example, you want to have 2 Clusters (k=2) colorized?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Workaround would be to plot cluster object with `plot()` and then use function `rect.hclust()` to draw borders around the clusters (nunber of clusters is set with argument `k=`). If result of `rect.hclust()` is saved as object it will make list of observation where each list element contains observations belonging to each cluster.

```
plot(hc)
gg<-rect.hclust(hc,k=2)
```

Now this list can be converted to dataframe where column `clust` contains names for clusters (in this example two groups) - names are repeated according to lengths of list elemets.

```
clust.gr<-data.frame(num=unlist(gg),
  clust=rep(c("Clust1","Clust2"),times=sapply(gg,length)))
head(clust.gr)
      num  clust
sta_1   1 Clust1
sta_2   2 Clust1
sta_3   3 Clust1
sta_5   5 Clust1
sta_8   8 Clust1
sta_9   9 Clust1
```

New data frame is merged with `label()` information of `dendr` object (`dendro_data()` result).

```
text.df<-merge(label(dendr),clust.gr,by.x="label",by.y="row.names")
head(text.df)
   label  x y num  clust
1  sta_1  8 0   1 Clust1
2 sta_10 28 0  10 Clust2
3 sta_11 41 0  11 Clust2
4 sta_12 31 0  12 Clust2
5 sta_13 10 0  13 Clust1
6 sta_14 37 0  14 Clust2
```

When plotting dendrogram use `text.df` to add labels with `geom_text()` and use column `clust` for colors.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(data=segment(dendr), aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) + 
  geom_text(data=text.df, aes(x=x, y=y, label=label, hjust=0,color=clust), size=3) +
  coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0.2, 0)) + 
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
        panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 24):

This approach is very similar to @DidzisElferts', just a little simpler.

```
df   <- USArrests                 # really bad idea to muck up internal datasets
labs <- paste("sta_",1:50,sep="") # new labels
rownames(df) <- labs              # set new row names

library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
hc       <- hclust(dist(df), "ave")           # heirarchal clustering
dendr    <- dendro_data(hc, type="rectangle") # convert for ggplot
clust    <- cutree(hc,k=2)                    # find 2 clusters
clust.df <- data.frame(label=names(clust), cluster=factor(clust))
# dendr[["labels"]] has the labels, merge with clust.df based on label column
dendr[["labels"]] <- merge(dendr[["labels"]],clust.df, by="label")
# plot the dendrogram; note use of color=cluster in geom_text(...)
ggplot() + 
  geom_segment(data=segment(dendr), aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend)) + 
  geom_text(data=label(dendr), aes(x, y, label=label, hjust=0, color=cluster), 
           size=3) +
  coord_flip() + scale_y_reverse(expand=c(0.2, 0)) + 
  theme(axis.line.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        panel.background=element_rect(fill="white"),
        panel.grid=element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I new that there was another function to cut dendrogram but forgot about cutree :)

Answer (score 14):

Adding to @DidzisElferts' and @jlhoward's code, the dendrogram itself can be coloured.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
library(plyr)
library(zoo)

df <- USArrests                       # really bad idea to muck up internal datasets
labs <- paste("sta_", 1:50, sep = "") # new labels
rownames(df) <- labs                  # set new row names

cut <- 4    # Number of clusters
hc <- hclust(dist(df), "ave")              # hierarchical clustering
dendr <- dendro_data(hc, type = "rectangle") 
clust <- cutree(hc, k = cut)               # find 'cut' clusters
clust.df <- data.frame(label = names(clust), cluster = clust)

# Split dendrogram into upper grey section and lower coloured section
height <- unique(dendr$segments$y)[order(unique(dendr$segments$y), decreasing = TRUE)]
cut.height <- mean(c(height[cut], height[cut-1]))
dendr$segments$line <- ifelse(dendr$segments$y == dendr$segments$yend &
   dendr$segments$y > cut.height, 1, 2)
dendr$segments$line <- ifelse(dendr$segments$yend  > cut.height, 1, dendr$segments$line)

# Number the clusters
dendr$segments$cluster <- c(-1, diff(dendr$segments$line))
change <- which(dendr$segments$cluster == 1)
for (i in 1:cut) dendr$segments$cluster[change[i]] = i + 1
dendr$segments$cluster <-  ifelse(dendr$segments$line == 1, 1, 
             ifelse(dendr$segments$cluster == 0, NA, dendr$segments$cluster))
dendr$segments$cluster <- na.locf(dendr$segments$cluster) 

# Consistent numbering between segment$cluster and label$cluster
clust.df$label <- factor(clust.df$label, levels = levels(dendr$labels$label))
clust.df <- arrange(clust.df, label)
clust.df$cluster <- factor((clust.df$cluster), levels = unique(clust.df$cluster), labels = (1:cut) + 1)
dendr[["labels"]] <- merge(dendr[["labels"]], clust.df, by = "label")

# Positions for cluster labels
n.rle <- rle(dendr$segments$cluster)
N <- cumsum(n.rle$lengths)
N <- N[seq(1, length(N), 2)] + 1
N.df <- dendr$segments[N, ]
N.df$cluster <- N.df$cluster - 1

# Plot the dendrogram
ggplot() + 
   geom_segment(data = segment(dendr), 
      aes(x=x, y=y, xend=xend, yend=yend, size=factor(line), colour=factor(cluster)), 
      lineend = "square", show.legend = FALSE) + 
   scale_colour_manual(values = c("grey60", rainbow(cut))) +
   scale_size_manual(values = c(.1, 1)) +
   geom_text(data = N.df, aes(x = x, y = y, label = factor(cluster),  colour = factor(cluster + 1)), 
      hjust = 1.5, show.legend = FALSE) +
   geom_text(data = label(dendr), aes(x, y, label = label, colour = factor(cluster)), 
       hjust = -0.2, size = 3, show.legend = FALSE) +
   scale_y_reverse(expand = c(0.2, 0)) + 
   labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
   coord_flip() +
    theme(axis.line.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

The 2-cluster and 4-cluster solutions:
[image]

Comment: Muito Muito Bom! Obrigado.

Comment: Ao utilizar o método "ward.D" em `hclust()` tive problemas com as etiquetas  dos grupos gráfico. Não consegui resolver. Tens alguma dica para isto?

Comment: O que citei acima acontece também com o "ave". A etiqueta do Cluster em `clust.df` não necessariamente é igual a produzida no gráfico!!!

Comment: @Jean I think I understand, but I cannot reply in Portuguese. I will look into your problem a little later. In the meantime, you might want to compare these responses with what the `dendextend` package can do.

Comment: Ta bem. Vou examinar o pacote. Tenho um trabalho pra entregar e acabei utilizando os retângulos básicos para demostrar os grupos. Para o momento está de bom. Lhe questionei por puro interesse no modelo do gráfico. Ficou muito didático (Parabéns!) . Caso encontre uma solução ou tenha uma dica, vou utilizar em outros trabalhos. Obrigado pelo retorno.

Comment: @Jean If I understand correctly: The labels for the clusters in the chart are not connected to any labels in cluster.df; the cluster labels in the chart are taken from N.df. The cluster labels in the chart are somewhat arbitrary; the only constraint is that the order in N.df is from bottom to top in the chart. The labels could be changed by adding a new label variable to N.df. Something like `N.df$NEWcluster <- LETTERS[1:cut]`. Then in the first `geom_text` line in the ggplot, change `label = factor(cluster)` to `label = factor(NEWcluster)`.

Comment: Apart from the colouring and the rotation, you can check that the ggplot dendrogram is the same as the hclust dendrogram, by `plot(hc)`.

Comment: Obrigado, vou verificar!

Answer (score 6):

A short way to achieve a similar result is to use the package `dendextend`, taken from this [overview](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/beautiful-dendrogram-visualizations-in-r-5-must-known-methods-unsupervised-machine-learning).

```
df   <- USArrests   # really bad idea to muck up internal datasets
labs <- paste("sta_",1:50,sep="") # new labels
rownames(df) <- labs # set new row names

require(magrittr)
require(ggplot2)
require(dendextend)

dend <- df %>% dist %>%
  hclust %>% as.dendrogram %>%
  set("branches_k_color", k = 4) %>% set("branches_lwd", 0.7) %>%
  set("labels_cex", 0.6) %>% set("labels_colors", k = 4) %>%
  set("leaves_pch", 19) %>% set("leaves_cex", 0.5) 
ggd1 <- as.ggdend(dend)
ggplot(ggd1, horiz = TRUE)
```

Note: The order of the states is slightly different compared to those above - not really changing interpretation though.

[image]

Comment: In this approach, how can we specify `hclust(dist(df,method="euclidean"),method="ward.D2")`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4057186/w-r
 ...df %>% dist(method="euclidean") %>%
  hclust(method="ward.D2") %>%...

Just skip the first argument in each function because it is the thing you piped to it

Answer (score 0):

For those that are still looking for a convenient way to do this, you can use my package [ggdendroplot](https://github.com/NicolasH2/ggdendroplot) (https://github.com/NicolasH2/ggdendroplot).

If you have the data from the posted example:

```
labs = paste("sta_",1:50,sep="") #new labels
rownames(USArrests)<-labs #set new row names
hc <- hclust(dist(USArrests), "ave")
```

...you can use ggdendroplot with ggplot to get a colored dendrogram:

```
devtools::install_github("NicolasH2/ggdendroplot")

library(ggdendroplot)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() + geom_dendro(hc, dendrocut = 30)
```

You can turn it sideways and on its head etc. Its basically just a ggplot layer, so you can modify the graph further as you wish and add it to other ggplots. Check out the [github page](https://github.com/NicolasH2/ggdendroplot) to see what you can do with ggdendroplot.

[image]