# Adding scale on dendrogram

Tags: r, dendrogram

I am plotting a heatmap on R which also outputs dendrograms (horizontally and vertically). I would like to add the scale on the horizontal dendrogram (similar to [horizontal dendrogram in R with labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118033/horizontal-dendrogram-in-r-with-labels)) so as to help me choose the cut off but keeping the heatmap. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: This might be tricky with the plain-vanilla `heatmap()`-function, because it comes with a specific `add.expr`-parameter that can be used to decorate the main matrix, but I see no comparable means to graphically complement the dendrograms...

Comment: Just a heads up that a lot of us will ignore posts that do not have a reproducible example.