# R: Customized dendrogram - different leave node color and type by label

Tags: r, fonts, colors, dendrogram, dendextend

I have written the following MWE using dendextend ([vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dendextend/vignettes/introduction.html)):

```
library(cluster)
library(ggdendro)
library(dendextend)
d1 <- c(paste(rep("firstcelltype",7),1:7,sep="_"), paste(rep("secondcelltype", 3),1:3,sep="_"))
d1.df <- as.data.frame(t(combn(d1,2)))
set.seed(1)
d1.df$DIST <- sample(1:100, 45)
dmat <- with(d1.df, structure(DIST,
        Size = length(d1),
        Labels = d1,
        Diag = FALSE,
        Upper = FALSE,
        method = "user",
        class = "dist"))
c1 <- hclust(dmat, method="complete")
dend <- as.dendrogram(c1)
vals <- grep("second", d1, val=TRUE)
dend <- dend %>% set("leaves_pch", 19) %>%
        set("leaves_cex", 2) %>%
        set("by_labels_branches_col", value = vals, TF_values = c(2,Inf)) %>%
        set("by_labels_branches_lwd", value = vals, TF_values = c(4,2))
tiff("test.tiff")
mar.default <- c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
par(mar = mar.default + c(0, 0, 0, 5)) 
plot(dend, main = "MY TITLE", xlab="my.X", horiz=TRUE)
dev.off()
```

What I do here is just create a distance matrix with all the possible combinations of my labels in "d1" and some random values as distances.

I make a dendrogram out of the hclust results, and save it in the following TIFF file:
[image: test.tiff]

As you see, I have been able to change the branches for "secondcelltype", but I need help to do the following, if it is even possible to do:

> 1 - Change "secondcelltype" leave node to a red square
>
> 2 - Change "secondcelltype" label to red (and maybe bold or italic)
>
> 3 - Change font everywhere to Arial

I would really appreciate some help here! If there is a better way to do this than with dendextend please let me know. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some responses:

1) You don't need ggdendro here

2) You need to use:

```
    set("labels_colors", ifelse(ss_change, 2, 1)) %>%
    set("leaves_pch", ifelse(ss_change, 15, 19)) %>%
    set("leaves_col", ifelse(ss_change, 2, 1))
```

3) I can't see an Ariel option, but you can use Standard values like "serif", "sans" and "mono" by using `par(family = "sans")`

Here is a code that does what you asked for:

```
library(cluster)
library(dendextend)
d1 <- c(paste(rep("firstcelltype",7),1:7,sep="_"), paste(rep("secondcelltype", 3),1:3,sep="_"))
d1.df <- as.data.frame(t(combn(d1,2)))
set.seed(1)
d1.df$DIST <- sample(1:100, 45)
dmat <- with(d1.df, structure(DIST,
        Size = length(d1),
        Labels = d1,
        Diag = FALSE,
        Upper = FALSE,
        method = "user",
        class = "dist"))
c1 <- hclust(dmat, method="complete")
dend <- as.dendrogram(c1)
vals <- grep("second", d1, val=TRUE)

ss_change <- grepl("secondcelltype", labels(dend))

dend <- dend %>% 
        set("labels_colors", ifelse(ss_change, 2, 1)) %>%
        set("leaves_pch", ifelse(ss_change, 15, 19)) %>%
        set("leaves_col", ifelse(ss_change, 2, 1)) 
# str(unclass(dend))
# plot(dend)

dend <- dend %>% 
        set("leaves_cex", 2) %>%
        set("by_labels_branches_col", value = vals, TF_values = c(2,Inf)) %>%
        set("by_labels_branches_lwd", value = vals, TF_values = c(4,2))


par(family = "sans")
mar.default <- c(5,4,4,2) + 0.1
par(mar = mar.default + c(0, 0, 0, 5)) 
plot(dend, main = "MY TITLE", xlab="my.X", horiz=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I was trying the approach in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118033/horizontal-dendrogram-in-r-with-labels/14118735#14118735 but for some reason c(a$nodePar, list(col='blue', lab.col='blue', pch=15)) changes col and lab.col but not pch...

Comment: If you are able to find out changing font to Arial please update! Thanks!

Comment: @DaniCee you are welcome. Solving these problems with dendrapply manually can be VERY tedious (because it requires some understanding of how the information is stored). This was part of my motivation for writing dendextend. As for the fonts, I think it may be worth a SO question by itself (and see if others have suggestions). Cheers, Tal

Comment: @TalGalili I have similar question but with regards to pvclust where I would like to add metada info such as group info instead of labeling the sample name which is difficult I would like to label it just the metadata or subtype ..I did find some ggraph and tidyverse ways but if I dendextend would make life easier

Comment: @TalGalili I have asked a question i would love to if you could give some insight how to use dendextend here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72936380/adding-group-information-to-pvclust-dendrogram-instead-of-sample-name