# Adding group information to pvclust dendrogram instead of sample name

Tags: r, dendrogram, dendextend, pvclust

This is what I'm doing

```
mat <-  read.table("Model_pvclust/Model18_FAB_M5_vs_M0_MAP_TF.txt",sep = "\t",strip.white = FALSE,check.names = FALSE,header=TRUE,row.names=1)
drop <- c("gene","baseMean","log2FoldChange","lfcSE","stat","pvalue","padj","UP_DOWN")

d1 <- select(mat, -one_of(drop))
```

####### Read the metadata

```
metadata <-read.table("Model_hmap_meta/FAB_table.txt",sep = "\t",strip.white = FALSE,check.names = FALSE,header=TRUE,row.names=1)
head(metadata)



head(metadata)
             prior_malignancy FAB    Risk_Cyto
TCGA-AB-2856               no  M4 Intermediate
TCGA-AB-2849               no  M0         Poor
TCGA-AB-2971               no  M4 Intermediate
TCGA-AB-2930               no  M2 Intermediate
TCGA-AB-2891               no  M1         Poor
TCGA-AB-2872               no  M3         Good
```

#### Plotting the cluster

```
pvc <- pvclust( data = d1 , method.dist = "correlation", method.hclust = "complete",parallel = T)
plot(pvc,las=2,hang = -0.5)
pvrect(pvc, alpha = 0.9)
```

Image that i get is where My sample names are labelled. Instead of those sample names I would like to label them based on that FAB columns matching the sample name order.

My data files [mat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gidgAGFRbns-QKjN-1vNw7bU3uuzJsrt/view?usp=sharing) and my [metadata](https://drive.google.com/file/d/166uvBILwD9qHwf_g3h8WdgxqQxZ_muir/view?usp=sharing)

[image: pvclust figure]

Updated answer[image: updated image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replace the current labels using the `dendextend::labels` function.

```
library("dendextend")
labels(pvc$hclust) <- metadata$FAB
plot(pvc,las=2,hang = -0.5)
pvrect(pvc, alpha = 0.9)
```

[image]

Comment: wow let me run...

Comment: Im getting numbers in my label not the FAB label ..I wil attach the image why is it so? I ran the code you have provided in the answer...updated the figure in my question have a look what is wrong here i would like to know

Comment: Not sure where it is going wrong... the `metadata$FAB` I ran is in character format. Check that it is also the same for you, and the read table did not force the string as factor.

Comment: okay ..let me run....that class `metadata$FAB` I see in my R its in factor ..need to change that..

Comment: Thank you @Adam it my 6 hours of search ends with your 4 line of code although i did find long way of doing through ggplot2 but it was too much code..this is simple thanks again..

Comment: No problem. I'd learned something myself. :D

Comment: Glad you got it resolved. Thanks Adam for taking a look and giving a solution :)

Comment: @AdamQuek any thoughts on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72958698/adding-group-information-to-3d-plot-in-factoextra  is it hard-coded ? or it can be modified since the pakacgae manager is not active in  github for quite sometimes

Comment: Not used factoextra before (only FactoMineR). But if you are trying to run unsupervised clustering over dimension reduction ordination (pca), wouldn't it be better to stick with more conventional approaches, e.g. k-means clustering? See some of the discussion at cross-validated  e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235946/pca-before-cluster-analysis